# @clerk/clerk-expo - prepareEmailAddressVerification

Tags: react-native, clerk

I'm getting an error when trying to send a email verification using clerk/expo

```js
 try {
   const signupResponse = await signUp.create({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        emailAddress,
        password,
      });
      const response = await signupResponse.prepareEmailAddressVerification({
        strategy: "email_code",
      });
 } catch (err: any) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
```

`signUp.create` works fine, however `signupResponse.prepareEmailAddressVerification` returns

```json
{
  "status": 400,
  "clerkError": true,
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "client_state_invalid",
      "message": "Invalid action",
      "longMessage": "We were unable to complete a get for this Client. No sign up.",
      "meta": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Enviroment: **Android**

I have tried using either the object from `signUp.create` or from `signupResponse` but both returns the same error

EDIT: Fixed by recreating a new clerk instance in their painel, looks like I've probably changed a config I should have not changed

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by recreating a new clerk instance in their painel, looks like I've probably changed a config I should have not changed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).